How to convert a proof in one proof system to a proof in another?
I'm currently reading "Logical Methods" by Restall, Standefer and have started having trouble with a question involving converting proofs from intuitionistic logic to so-called J-logic. 

Please write up question with mathjax rather than uploading pjctures here.

What does this question have to do with proof assistants? it belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com, not here.

@AndrejBauer you have the power to move it, right?

Do I? I don't see any buttons that would let me.

I don't know if it shows up for @AndrejBauer but it should be in the "Close" menu, under "A community specific reason".
